# Python SQLite3 SELECT results in vector array

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib

During data retrieval from the database, my data is converted from a scalar array to a vector array somewhere between the following code:

```
def analysis():
labels = ["Appearance", "Hygiene", "Staff", "Quality", "Value", "Overall"]
survey_mean = []
industry_mean = []
conn = sqlite3.connect('mysteryshopper.db')
c = conn.cursor()
avg1 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(appearance) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg1s = c.fetchall()
print (avg1s)
avg2 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(hygiene) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg2s = c.fetchall()
avg3 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(staff) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg3s = c.fetchall()
avg4 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(quality) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg4s = c.fetchall()
avg5 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(value) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg5s = c.fetchall()
avg6 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(overall) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg6s = c.fetchall()
parameter_survey = [avg1s, avg2s, avg3s, avg4s, avg5s, avg6s]
survey_mean.append(parameter_survey)
print (survey_mean)
```

The original data, before inserted into the database, is in the format of "(3.9)".

Testing the avg1s above outputs "(3.9,)", with an additional comma in the array seemingly out of nowhere and this causes further issues with my matplotlib task.

Comment: In Python, single values in parentheses with comma are actually tuples of one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `fetchone` since averages return one row and even combine all queries into one. Then, unpack the result to separate variables or convert cursor fetch into list:

```
sql = """SELECT avg(appearance) AS avg_appearance,
                avg(hygiene) AS avg_hygiene,
                avg(staff) AS avg_staff,
                avg(quality) AS avg_quality,
                avg(value) AS avg_value,
                avg(overall) AS avg_overall
         FROM survey 
         WHERE storeid = 1
      """

c.execute(sql)
avg1s, avg2s, avg3s, avg4s, avg5s, avg6s = c.fetchone()

parameter_survey = [avg1s, avg2s, avg3s, avg4s, avg5s, avg6s]
# parameter_survey = list(c.fetchone())  # ALTERNATIVE
survey_mean.append(parameter_survey)
print(survey_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing as a vector array in what sql can return. But `fetchall` returns a list of rows, and a row is an iterable of field values (by default a tuple or a list).

What you want is:

```
avg1 = c.execute ("""SELECT avg(appearance) FROM survey WHERE storeid = 1 """)
avg1s = [row[0] for row in avg1s]
```

(because a cursor is directly an iterable of rows)